# syntax for SetKeyDelay in Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

In a application I am using, I want to
1. Create a new record (Ctrl+n)
2. Paste value from clip board (Ctrl+v)
3. Save record (Ctrl+s)
when I just press "q", seems like creation of new record takes some time, so I have tried adding both SetKeyDelay and sleep, but in both the cases the script is trying to save the record before the value is pasted, am I missing something?

> Q::Send, ^n SetKeyDelay, 100 ^v^s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the process takes some time, I would suggest putting some `Sleep` times in there like so:

```
Q::
    ;SetKeyDelay, 100 ; Not needed in this example, but this is where it would go
    Send ^n
    Sleep 50
    Send ^v       
    Sleep 50
    Send ^s
    Return
```

Comment: Thanks Elliot, but the script is trying to save the record before the value is pasted in the field. Is there any thing else I am missing?

Comment: Are you certain your clipboard contains something? If so, is your caret somewhere that text can be entered?

Comment: Yes Elliot, if I do the same steps manually it is working

Comment: With the information given, the only other suggestion I have for you is to perform either a `ControlFocus` or a `MouseClick` to ensure your caret is in the correct location. Programmatically, my answer is sound and answered the original question for the syntax of SetKeyDelay. Please mark it accepted if it helped you out.

Comment: Script worked perfectly with ControlFocus, thanks a lot Elliot.